# Calendar with grid display - vertical align notes/tasks at the bottom of the grid cell one above another

Tags: html, css, css-grid, vertical-alignment

I am currently implementing a calendar. I have used the grid layout for displaying the calendar day cells. I want to display some tasks/notes of different types as strips in some grid cells. The tasks should be vertically aligned in the bottom border of the cell without affecting the display of calendar day cell. The width of the task strips should fit(touch both the left and right border of the cell) the cell width(100%). If there are more than one task in a day cell(for example, May 26), it should be aligned one above another with a 2px gap between them.

[image]

The sample code is below. Can you help to achieve the expected design?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashlythomas/5wbzac1s/)

```
<div id="calendar_container" class="calendar-container">
    <div class="calendar-header-row">                    
        <span id="calendar_header" class="calendar-header">May 2020</span>

        <span id="prev_month" class="prevMonth" onclick="javascript: previousMonth()"><img src="/images/arrow_left.png"></span>

        <span id="next_month" class="nextMonth" onclick="javascript: nextMonth()"><img src="/images/arrow_right.png"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="calendar_body" class="calendar"><div class="day-name">Sunday</div><div class="day-name">Monday</div><div class="day-name">Tuesday</div><div class="day-name">Wednesday</div><div class="day-name">Thursday</div><div class="day-name">Friday</div><div class="day-name">Saturday</div><div class="day"></div><div class="day"></div><div class="day"></div><div class="day"></div><div class="day"></div><div class="day">01</div><div class="day">02</div><div class="day">03</div><div class="day">04</div><div class="day">05</div><div class="day">06</div><div class="day">07</div><div class="day">08</div><div class="day">09</div><div class="day">10</div><div class="day">11</div><div class="day">12</div><div class="day">13</div><div class="day">14</div><div class="day">15</div><div class="day">16</div><div class="day">17</div><div class="day">18</div><div class="day">19</div><div class="day">20</div><div class="day">21</div><div class="day">22</div><div class="day">23</div><div class="day">24</div><div class="day">25</div><div class="day">26<div class="task error">Error 1 here</div><div class="task info2">Info 2 here<span class="circle" style="padding-left: 7px;">3</span></div><div class="task error2">Error 2 here</div></div><div class="day">27</div><div class="day">28</div><div class="day">29</div><div class="day">30</div><div class="day">31</div><div class="task warning">Warning here</div><div class="task info">Info here</div></div>
</div>



<style>

.calendar-container {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.calendar-header-row {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.calendar-header {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;

    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.prevMonth, .nextMonth {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;

    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.calendar {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(120px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
    grid-auto-rows: 120px;
}

.day-name {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #cccccc;

    border-right: 1px solid #b9b9b9;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 20px;

    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;

    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.day {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-right: 1px solid #b9b9b9;

    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px 20px;

    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;

    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}


.day:nth-of-type(7n + 7) {
    border-right: 2px;
}

.day:nth-of-type(n + 1):nth-of-type(-n + 7) {
    grid-row: 1;
}

.day:nth-of-type(n + 8):nth-of-type(-n + 14) {
    grid-row: 2;
}

.day:nth-of-type(n + 15):nth-of-type(-n + 21) {
    grid-row: 3;
}

.day:nth-of-type(n + 22):nth-of-type(-n + 28) {
    grid-row: 4;
}

.day:nth-of-type(n + 29):nth-of-type(-n + 35) {
    grid-row: 5;
}

.day:nth-of-type(n + 36):nth-of-type(-n + 42) {
    grid-row: 6;
}

.day:nth-of-type(7n + 1) {
    grid-column: 1/1;
}

.day:nth-of-type(7n + 2) {
    grid-column: 2/2;
}

.day:nth-of-type(7n + 3) {
    grid-column: 3/3;
}

.day:nth-of-type(7n + 4) {
    grid-column: 4/4;
}

.day:nth-of-type(7n + 5) {
    grid-column: 5/5;
}

.day:nth-of-type(7n + 6) {
    grid-column: 6/6;
}
.day:nth-of-type(7n + 7) {
    grid-column: 7/7;
}

.task {
    border-left-width: 5px;
    border-left-style: solid;

    padding: 4px 4px;
    background-color: #8f8f8f;
    color: #ffffff;

    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;

    height: min-content;
}

.info {
    border-left-color: #348401;
}

.warning {
    border-left-color: #e5941f;

}

.error {
    border-left-color: #c70623;
}

.info2 {
    border-left-color: #348401;
}

.error2 {
    border-left-color: #c70623;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;

    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #348401;

    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Please let me know if this is possible using the grid layout?
Otherwise, I have to use some other layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following changes in the particular cell:

```
<div class="day">
<div>26</div>
<div class="task error">Error 1 here</div>
<div class="task info2">Info 2 here<span class="circle" style="padding-left: 7px;">3</span></div>
<div class="task error2">Error 2 here</div>
</div>
```

and

```
    .day {
        /*  position: relative; */
        z-index: 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
        border-right: 1px solid #b9b9b9;

        /*  text-align: left;
        padding: 16px 20px; */

        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000000;
        pointer-events: none;
        user-select: none;

        /* The flex layout will do the trick */
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .day > div {
        /* Set size of the container according to the content */
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }

    .day > div:first-child {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 16px 20px;
        padding-bottom: 0;

        /* To shift the tasks to the bottom of the cell */
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }
```

the above CSS modification worked for me to achieve the required layout.